# Searching for Multiple Strings within another String using any()

Tags: python, string, any

I'm using Python 3.4.2 at the moment but am not getting the expected results when attempting to search for a number of strings within another string.

I create a set which contains items with a string format similar to TEXT.NA[Y]ABC.  I'm trying to only catch items of the set which contain a .NA, .SA or .EU as an example.

```
testset = set()
testset.add(('Blah','TEXT.NA[Y]ABC'))
testset.add(('Bleh','OTHER.AU[X]DEF'))
region = ['.NA', '.SA', '.EU']
for text,key in testset:
    if any(sym in region for sym in key):
        print(key)
```

I was expecting the above to print TEXT.NA[Y]ABC while skipping OTHER.AU[X]DEF
Wondering what I'm doing wrong in my iterable.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your membership checking is wrong. You need to check if any item from `region` is in `key`:

```
>>> for text,key in testset:
...     if any(sym in key for sym in region):
...         print(key)
... 
TEXT.NA[Y]ABC
```

Comment: Ah thank you that looks like it did the trick.  I had my understanding of how to set up the iterator backwards. Thank you very much!